# How is my url getting my text input as parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a form on my main asp.net mvc page and when I enter text into the text box 'location' and hit the 'submit' input button it passes the value from the text box as parameters in the url. Why is this and how do I change it so that I can pass in whatever I want as parameters and not just the text from the text box? How is the routing engine getting the text from the input box?

Here is what the url looks like and the form code below

```
https://localhost:44300/Home/Results?location=San+Francisco

@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Search For A Studio" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value='Submit' type="submit"/>
    </p>
}
```

Comment: Your doing a  `FormMethod.Get` which adds the form values as query string parameters (unsure why you doing this as opposed to a post using `FormMethod.Post`). You can add route values using one of the overloads of [BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) that accepts `routeValues` - e.g. `Html.BeginForm("Results", "Home", new { someParameter = someValue }, FormMethod.Get`

Comment: Its not really clear what your wanting to do. You might use FormMethod.GET for (say) a search parameter where you post back to `ActionResult Results(string location) and the return a view based on the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

```
@{
    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
    routeValues.Add("Longitude", "5");
    routeValues.Add("Latitude", "6");
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Home", routeValues, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Search For A Studio" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value='Submit' type="submit"/>
    </p>
}
```

This gives me a route of

```
http://someWebsiteName/Home/Results&Longitude=5&Latitude=6
```